# Use of CORS in Firebase Functions in Python to set allow-headers

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am setting CORS in the following way

```py
from firebase_functions.options import CorsOptions
from firebase_functions import https_fn

@https_fn.on_request(cors=CorsOptions(cors_origins=['*'], cors_methods=['POST']))
def my_function(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
   pass
```

However, I am noticing two problems:

1. There is no way to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers".
2. The headers I am getting back do not include "Access-Control-Allow-Methods=POST" even though I have set that option.

In the meantime I am using my own decorator but I would prefer to use the official one:

```py
def handle_cors(fn: Callable, allowed_origins: Union[list[str], None] = None,
                allowed_methods: Union[list[str], None] = None) -> Callable:
    if allowed_origins is None:
        allowed_origins = ['*']
    if allowed_methods is None:
        allowed_methods = ['POST']

    @functools.wraps(fn)  # preserves fn's name, docstring, etc.
    def wrapper(req: https_fn.Request):
        if req.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return https_fn.Response(status=204,
                                     headers={
                                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ', '.join(allowed_origins),
                                            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': ', '.join(allowed_methods),
                                            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
                                            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'})
        return fn(req)
    return wrapper
```